# Determining local area change from surface displacement field

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, displacement

In continuum mechanics, deformed area elements are related to initial area elements by Nanson's formula:

$$\vec{n}\ da = (\det{\pmb{F}})(\pmb{F}^{-T}\cdot \vec{N})dA$$

Assuming one can experimentally only access the displacement field on a surface, e.g. $z(x,y)$ , how is the local area change $\frac{da}{dA}$ then calculated from the displacement field $\vec{u}(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} u_x \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{pmatrix} (x,y)$?

In that case I'm not sure how derivatives in $z$-direction, e.g. $F_{xz} = \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z} $, are evaluated, as the displacement is only defined on the surface (= definite $z$) and not above/ below. Is it valid to assume $\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z} = 0$ (implicating that the infinitesimally upper and lower planes are displaced by the same amount in z-direction), such that $\pmb{F} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y} & 0 \\ \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x} & 1 + \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y} & 0\\ \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial y} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Or is there a simpler solution apart from Nanson's Formula to evaluate the local area change $\frac{da}{dA}$ from a displacement field on a surface?

Comment: Is the surface displaced so that x and y change, of is it just z that changes?  Or are x and y embedded material coordinates within the surface?

Comment: The surface is displaced such that x,y and z changes. An exemplary case would be a circular membrane fixed on the sides in the xy-plane actuated by a pressure from below. x, y, z are the displaced coordinates of the surface in the lab coordinate system, X, Y, Z the initial coordinates.

Comment: So in the initial configuration, the entire surface lies in the x-y plane?

Comment: it can lie in the x-y plane but not necesserily. I tried to extend your great answer to an arbitrary initial surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in the initial configuration, the entire surface lies in the x-y plane, the locations of the material points in the deformed configuration of the surface can be expressed parametrically in terms of their coordinates in the undeformed configuration as:
$$x=x(X,Y)\tag{1-a}$$$$y=y(X,Y)\tag{1-b}$$$$z=z(X,Y)\tag{1-c}$$An arbitrary differential position vector between two neighboring material points in the deformed configuration at original locations in the undeformed configuration of $(X,Y)$ and $(X+dX, Y+dY)$ can be expressed as $$\mathbf{ds}=dx\mathbf{i_x}+dy\mathbf{i_y}+dz\mathbf{i_z}=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_z}\right)dX+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_z}\right)dY=\mathbf{a_X}dX+\mathbf{a_Y}dY\tag{2}$$where $$\mathbf{a_X}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_z}=\left(1+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial X}\right)\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_z}\tag{3a}$$and$$\mathbf{a_Y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_z}=\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_x}+\left(1+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial Y}\right)\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_z}\tag{3b}$$The rectangular region in the original configuration between between material edges $\mathbf{i_x}dX$ and $\mathbf{i_y}dY$ has an initial area of dXdY, and deforms into a parallelogram with edges $\mathbf{a_X}dX$ and $\mathbf{a_Y}dY$. The area of this material parallelogram is $$dA=|\mathbf{a_X}\times \mathbf{a_Y}|dXdY\tag{4}$$
So the area ratio $\Lambda=dA/(dXdY)$ is given by $$\Lambda=|\mathbf{a_X}\times \mathbf{a_Y}|\tag{5}$$The cross product is given by: $$\mathbf{a_X}\times \mathbf{a_Y}=\left[\left(1+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial Y}\right)\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial X}-\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial X}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial Y}\right]\mathbf{i_x}+\left[\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial X}\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial Y}-\left(1+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial X}\right)\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial Y}\right]\mathbf{i_y}+\left[\left(1+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial X}\right)\left(1+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial Y}\right)-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial X}\right]\mathbf{i_z}\tag{6}$$Another way of getting the area of the parallelogram is to write $$dA=|\mathbf{a_X}||\mathbf{a_Y}|\sin{\theta}\tag{7}$$where $\theta$ is the included angle.  We also know that $$\cos{\theta}=\frac{\mathbf{a_X}\centerdot \mathbf{a_Y}}{|\mathbf{a_X}||\mathbf{a_Y}|}\tag{8}$$This leads to $$dA=dXdY\sqrt{g_{XX}g_{YY}-(g_{XY})^2}$$or$$\Lambda=\sqrt{g_{XX}g_{YY}-(g_{XY})^2}\tag{9}$$ where $$g_{XX}=\mathbf{a_X}\centerdot \mathbf{a_X}$$
$$g_{XY}=\mathbf{a_X}\centerdot \mathbf{a_Y}$$and $$g_{YY}=\mathbf{a_Y}\centerdot \mathbf{a_Y}$$

Comment: Would it be correct to say that this answer I gave does not work for you?  If so, why not?

Comment: Please excuse my quite delayed answer, your reply is perfectly fine. I was reflecting how shown resolution is related to the approach with Nanson's formula. Eq. (9) looks quite aesthetic, is this a generally known solution or did it just turn out like this for you?

Comment: When I was working on automobile tire mechanics, this equation arose naturally in the analysis.  This is a general area equation for a non-orthogonal set of coordinates in a deformed surface, expressed in terms of the components of the metric tensor.  And using two embedded material coordinates in an approach developed by Gauss in working with curved surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to extend Chet Miller's answer considering an initial configuration where the surface lies in the x-y plane to an arbitrary plane z(x,y) I obtain following initial area:

$dA_i=|\mathbf{t_X}\times \mathbf{t_Y}|dXdY\tag{1}$

where

$\mathbf{t_X} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_z} = \mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\mathbf{i_z} \tag{2a}$

and

$\mathbf{t_Y} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_x}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_z} = \mathbf{i_y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}\mathbf{i_z}\tag{2b}$

are the tangential vectors of the initial surface configuration. Therefore,

$dA_i=|\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial X} \end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y} \end{pmatrix}| dXdY = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X})^2 + (\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y})^2 + 1} \: dXdY \tag{3}$

such that the area change becomes:

$$\Lambda=\frac{\sqrt{g_{XX}g_{YY}-(g_{XY})^2}}{\sqrt{(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X})^2 + (\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y})^2 + 1}} \tag{4}$$

Comment: Looks good.  Nice job.